# Maximum likelihood estimator for bombing planes.

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

> The bombing planes are intersecting two lines of anti-aircraft
> defense. Each plane, regardless of the others, has probability
> $\theta$, true resemblance, and can be knocked down by the first line
> of defense and second line of defense. Probability $\theta$ is not
> known.  Of the n = 100 aircraft, $K_1$ = 40 were knocked down and
> $K_2$ = 20 were knocked down.
>
> - Compute likelihood for $K_1$ and $K_2$, $P_{\theta}(K_1=40, K_2=20)$.
>
> - Compute mle for $\theta$.

I assumed that $\theta$ is the probability of Bernoulli trails.
But how to compute mle and likelihood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, each plane has a probability $\theta$ to be hit when passing through each line of defense.

For the first line, $40$ planes were hit, probability is $\binom{100}{40}\theta^{40}(1-\theta)^{60}$.

For the second line, of the $60$ remaining planes, $20$ were hit, probability is $\binom{60}{20}\theta^{20}(1-\theta)^{40}$.

So the likelihood is
$$P_\theta(K_1=40,K_2=20) = \binom{100}{40}\theta^{40}(1-\theta)^{60}.\binom{60}{20}\theta^{20}(1-\theta)^{40} = \frac{100!}{(40!)^2 20!}\theta^{60}(1-\theta)^{100}$$
Taking the derivative, you find
$$P_\theta(K_1=40,K_2=20) = \frac{100!}{(40!)^2 20!}\theta^{59}(1-\theta)^{99}\left[60-160\theta\right]$$
so the maximum likelihood is $\theta=\dfrac{60}{160}=\dfrac38$.

Comment: I think the derivative may not have the $\theta^{60}$ term but this does not affect your final answer

Comment: You're right. Corrected.

Comment: It's correct answer? In my opinion $\theta$ should be negative ...

Comment: $\theta$ is a probability, remember ?